# removing an entry from JSON using powershell

Tags: json, powershell, google-cloud-platform

I am using GCP's BigQuery. I want to remove access of someone. Per https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#bq_1, I run the command

```
   bq show \
--format=prettyjson \
project1:dataset1 > /tmp/myjson.json
```

and here is the JSON I get

```
 {
  "access": [
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "specialGroup": "projectWriters"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "specialGroup": "projectOwners"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "userByEmail": "employee1@myco.com"
    },
    {
      "role": "READER",
      "specialGroup": "projectReaders"
    }
  ],
  "creationTime": "1528762487037",
  "datasetReference": {
    "datasetId": "dataset1",
    "projectId": "project1"
  },
  "description": "My Data",
  "etag": "<redacted>",
  "friendlyName": "dataset1",
  "id": "project1:dataset1",
  "kind": "bigquery#dataset",
  "lastModifiedTime": "1528762487037",
  "location": "US",
  "selfLink": "https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project1/datasets/dataset1"
}
```

I an new to powershell and am trying to remove the entry for employee1, and put the json back for the

```
bq update
```

command per the link above.
Any ideas how to get the index of the entry.
I have tried to just get the "access" part of the json as an Array object. But the challenge is to find the employee1 entry index and remove that Array member and put it back into the json.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `convertfrom-json` cmdlet, you get an object you can edit.  Then you can convert it back using `convertto-json`

```
$x=@'
{
  "access": [
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "specialGroup": "projectWriters"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "specialGroup": "projectOwners"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "userByEmail": "employee1@myco.com"
    },
    {
      "role": "READER",
      "specialGroup": "projectReaders"
    }
  ],
  "creationTime": "1528762487037",
  "datasetReference": {
    "datasetId": "dataset1",
    "projectId": "project1"
  },
  "description": "My Data",
  "etag": "<redacted>",
  "friendlyName": "dataset1",
  "id": "project1:dataset1",
  "kind": "bigquery#dataset",
  "lastModifiedTime": "1528762487037",
  "location": "US",
  "selfLink": "https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project1/datasets/dataset1"
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-json
$x.Access=$x.Access.Where({$_.userByEmail -ne 'employee1@myco.com'})
$x | convertto-json
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, It almost works. Your code now gives me just the access section of the json minus the employee1 (which is great). But now, how do I get the complete json (with other sections like description, etag etc.

Comment: When I run the code I get everything.  Are you sure you have `$x` on the last line and not `$x.Access`?

Comment: My bad Mike. Sorry for the oversight. Yes you are correct, I messed it up. /Thanks again for the help.